# Applescript GUI scripting: Can't make button into type UI element

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to control [Napkin](http://aged-and-distilled.com) with Applescript. It doesn't have a built-in dictionary, so I need to use GUI scripting. I found the button I want to click, but I'm not able to get it to click. How can I script a click for this button?

With the script below, I get this Applescript error: System Events got an error: Can’t make {button "Screenshot" of toolbar 1 of window "Napkin" of application process "Napkin"} into type UI element.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Napkin"
        tell toolbar of window 1
            set btnScreenshot to (first button where its title = "Screenshot")
            click btnScreenshot
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

When I open this button in the Accessibility Inspector, the button has a "press" action. Clicking that Perform button runs the Screenshot functionality -- just like clicking the toolbar button.

[image]

I tried `tell btnScreenshot to perform action "press"` but that gave me an error of "can't get action 'press'". Same with `perform action "AXPress"`. Also, asking for `every action of btnScreenshot` returns an empty set.

Comment: I think your best bet with GUI scripting is simulating a press by using an **Enter** key press. I think it's key code 36. Why? Because it's not in the Dictionary so it'll be harder to manipulate unfortunately

Comment: Try using: `tell toolbar 1 of window 1`

Comment: `tell toolbar 1 of window 1` worked! Thanks. (If you write that up as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.)